# Не работает скрипт поворота камеры

Tags: unity3d

Скрипт вообще не работает, хотя на экране нет ни одного UI:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class CamRotate : MonoBehaviour {

    private Touch initTouch = new Touch();
    public Camera cam;
    private float rotX;
    private float rotY;
    private Vector3 origRot;

    public float sens = 0.5f;

    void Start () {
            origRot = cam.transform.eulerAngles;
            rotX = origRot.x;
            rotY = origRot.y;
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
                    int pointerID = touch.fingerId;
                    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject (pointerID)) {
                            return;
                    } 
                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                            initTouch = touch;
                    } else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
                            float deltaX = initTouch.position.x - touch.position.x;
                            float deltaY = initTouch.position.y - touch.position.y;
                            rotX += deltaY * Time.deltaTime * sens;
                            rotY -= deltaX * Time.deltaTime * sens;
                            rotX = Mathf.Clamp (rotX, -80f, 80f);
                            cam.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (rotX, rotY, 0);
                    } else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
                            initTouch = new Touch ();
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

А если убрать эти строчки:

```
int pointerID = touch.fingerId;
                        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(pointerID)) {
                                return;
                        }
```

То скрипт работает, но очень криво. Если двигать пальцем медленно то камера поворачивается быстро и реагирует на малейшее движение пальца, но если двигать быстро, например при резком повороте, то наоборот начинает двигаться очень медленно.
Может кто подсказать где тут ошибка?